# How to get all elements with inline-style (style-attribute) start from a id of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all elements which have an inline-style and searching for it inside a div and all their children.

Example

```
<div id="idofstartdiv">
    <span style="color:red;"></span>
    <div>
        <div style="color:green"><span style="color:yellow;"></span><span></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I can get all the inline style by `$("[style]")` and I know to select the starting div by `$("#idofstartdiv")`.

How can I combine both selectors?

Comment: Please show us an example with an input, and an expected result

Comment: i've update my post with a short example

Comment: what do you expect to happen with that code

Comment: Like i wrote, i donT know how i can get all elements wich has a style attribute inside the starting div...like my question

Comment: So you combine it like any selector. `$("#id [style]")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine them by simply doing:

```
$("#idofstartdiv[style]")
```

This will get the element which has an id of `idofstartdiv` along with a `style` attribute. For getting all children of that id as the parent with a `style` attribute you can do:

```
$("#idofstartdiv").find("[style]")
```

As mentioned in other answers, you can also do:

```
$("#idofstartdiv [style]")
```

Comment: ok, i've update my post with a example. Does your code will work for it or your selector only return elements wich hav the ID and the Style? I looking for all wich are inside the id and have style-attr.!?

Comment: @mikeD I gave an example for getting children which have a `style` attribute which are in the parent that has an id of `idofstartdiv`.

Comment: ok, i understand, it seems that $("#idofstartdiv [style]") will return the same as $("#idofstartdiv").find("[style]") - i decide to use the "find" way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#idofstartdiv [style]") is this is what you are asking for? if not can you provide an example of what you are expecting, am not clear with your question.
```

Comment: it looks pretty simple, and i could be that i was looking for, i test it and come back, thanks for the moment

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative-

```
$("[style]",  "#idofstartdiv")
```

This will also return all the elements which have style attribute under the parent div-id "idofstartdiv".